# Creating a function with multiple names for a single argument using R

Tags: r

For example, I want the arguments of s OR sd OR sigma to mean the same exact thing.

```
upper = function(mean, sigma, s, sd) {
    s = sd = sigma
    value = mean + 2 * sigma
    return(value)
}
```

I want `upper(mean = 0, sd = 1)` and `upper(mean = 0, sigma = 1)` to give me the same result.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to leave your function signature as is, and then check internally for the first defined parameter from `sigma`, `s`, and `sd`.  We can use `missing` here to handle this:

```
upper <- function(mean, sigma, s, sd) {
    param = ifelse(!missing(sigma), sigma, ifelse(!missing(s), s, sd))
    value = mean + 2 * param
    return(value)
}

print(upper(mean=0, sigma=2))  # 4
print(upper(mean=0, s=2))      # 4
print(upper(mean=0, sd=2))     # 4
```

### Demo

But in general, I wonder why you think you need this functionality.  There is nothing wrong with exposing an interface and then expecting your function to be called a certain way.

Comment: If all are missing, including "sd", it gets a bit untidy.

Comment: @IanRiley And it should, if this function expects this parameter to be defined.  Typically in R, when some API fails, your whole script dies.

Comment: Indeed, but in this case the message only says 'sd' is missing, and it seems from the question that 'sigma' is primary option. So ideally, it should say either that 'sigma' is missing or that they are all missing. This would be easily provided with a third "ifelse()".

Answer (score 1):

You can match the arguments..ie `match.arg` to be able to select the argumentsthat you need from the function:

```
upper=function(mean,sd,...){
  a = match.call()
  sd = a[[match.arg(names(a),c("sd","sigma","sig"),several.ok = T)]]
  value = mean + 2 * sd
  return(value)
}

print(upper(mean=0, sigma=2))  # 4
print(upper(mean=0, s=2))      # 4
print(upper(mean=0, sd=2))     # 4
```

Comment: I like the way this fails meaningfully on "upper(0)". Effectively the error says there are three options and one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
fx <- function(x, sigma, ...) {
    sigma <- unlist(as.list(match.call())[c('sigma', 's', 'sd')])[1]
    return(sigma)
    }

c(fx(0, 1),
  fx(0, sigma=1),
  fx(0, s=2),
  fx(0, sd=3),
  fx(0, sd=3, s=2),
  fx(0, sd=3, s=2, sigma=1),
  fx(0, sig=1)
  )

# sigma sigma sigma    sd sigma sigma sigma 
#    1     1     2     3     2     1     1
```

Notice that "s=" is always treated as an abbreviation of "sigma=", so it could be removed from the second line of the function, viz., unlist(as.list(match.call())[c('sigma', 'sd')])[1].

But, if both "s=" and "sigma=" are given, the latter takes priority (see the second last test above).

Also, notice that "sigma" is named, so if needed, the function can check and respond to its source.

With just "fx(0)", "sigma" is NULL, which can be easily tested and a meaningful error message returned, if desired.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger!!!! Is there a way to remove the name? If not, it's ok! I appreciate the help

Comment: @KevinW, the name doesn't matter as you will use `sigma` internally within the function, and whatever you return after performing the process of the function will in in the form/structure you desire. However, being named, it allows you function to know where the value came from, if it needs to, so for some functions this might be a good thing. Anyway, it is easy to remove names attributes: `sigma[[1]]` give the value only, or  `names(sigma) <- NULL` removes the name attribute.